# Where do I set version of Asp.NET Core project?

Tags: asp.net-core, versioning, publish

I'm coming from desktop app world (WPF, WinForms), where you can version a project by simply right clicking it and setting the new version in properties.

That does not seem to be an option in Asp.NET Core application.  When I right-click on the project, I don't have a way of specifying the version anywhere:

[image]

What's the standard way of versioning published Asp.NET Core applications?

Comment: @CodeCaster That question refers to .net core, not asp.net core .  There is no AssemblyInfo.cs in asp.net core.

Comment: Did you try reading the answers, especially scrolling down to the screenshot of the Package tab?

Comment: @CodeCaster I assumed that page was meant only for generating NuGet packages.  Thanks.

Comment: Agreed, the naming could be considered to be a bit confusing.